# Java web service call from RDz

Tags: java, service, web, mainframe

I don't know how familiar anyone is with RDz, but if you know IBM mainframe stuff and how webservices work, then maybe you can help me.

My MF has a UNIX side, and a CICS side, and I need to put a java appplication on the UNIX side that can be called from CICS in which invokes a web service from the java program on the unix side, then returns some data.

Anyway, I have everything else working, but I need to know how to invoke a webservice with data that is being passed to me through a CommArea CAH parm. I am kind of a newb to webservice, but it's always nice to learn.

EDIT: This java program needs to be independent and be able to run on its own without any manual operation.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but if you are in control of a m/f, it should be easy to open a ticket with IBM :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking a web service from a CICS application is done via the [INVOKE SERVICE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_invokeservice.html) CICS API.

In order for this to work, you begin with the WSDL for the web service you wish to invoke.  You run the WSDL through an IBM-supplied program [DFHWS2LS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/reference/dfhws_ws2ls.html&resultof=%2522%2564%2566%2568%2577%2573%2532%256c%2573%2522%2520%2522%2564%2566%2568%2577%2573%2532%256c%2522%2520) (DFH is the IBM abbreviation for all things CICS, WS2LS means Web Service to Language Structure).  DFHWS2LS is part of what IBM calls the [Web Services Assistant](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/concepts/dfhws_utility.html).

Out of DFHWS2LS you will get a [web services binding (WSBIND) file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/concepts/dfhws_wsbind.html) and language structures.  The language structures you include in your program and move the data from the commarea into them.  The WSBIND file you provide to your CICS Systems Programmer so they can include it in the [pickup directory](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.exampleapplication.doc/topics/dfhxa_t241.html&resultof=%2522%2570%2569%2563%256b%2575%2570%2522%2520%2522%2564%2569%2572%2565%2563%2574%256f%2572%2579%2522%2520%2522%2564%2569%2572%2565%2563%2574%256f%2572%2569%2522%2520) for your [pipeline](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.exampleapplication.doc/topics/dfhxa_t241.html&resultof=%2522%2570%2569%2563%256b%2575%2570%2522%2520%2522%2564%2569%2572%2565%2563%2574%256f%2572%2579%2522%2520%2522%2564%2569%2572%2565%2563%2574%256f%2572%2569%2522%2520).  You must also create a [pipeline configuration file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/concepts/dfhws_pipelineconfig.html).

All of which is to say you have asked a very large question. :)  There are multi-day courses and books on this subject.

Comment: Yea I know I did :) Thanks for your answer, it help's a lot.